# Reason behind "Successfully reconciled" event on EKS \ K8S Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

Received 130 events in the last 3 days

I see that event on a new cluster, it functions properly, manages to pass successfully all health/liveness/functional requests

Is it a normal event that runs every X minutes?

I suspect it's related to the AWS load balancer controller but not sure how to proceed to explore that issue.

Here's the event object (Changed a bit the unique ids)

```
kind: Event
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: k8s-default-proxyngi-21j23klsu.16322252fc4d27866
  namespace: default
  selfLink: >-
    /api/v1/namespaces/default/events/k8s-default-proxyngi-21j23klsu.16322252fc4d27866
  uid: e6e56ba2-82b6-76aafb51c753
  resourceVersion: '1578355'
  creationTimestamp: '2021-02-21T12:52:52Z'
  managedFields:
    - manager: controller
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: v1
      time: '2021-02-21T12:52:52Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:count': {}
        'f:firstTimestamp': {}
        'f:involvedObject':
          'f:apiVersion': {}
          'f:kind': {}
          'f:name': {}
          'f:namespace': {}
          'f:resourceVersion': {}
          'f:uid': {}
        'f:lastTimestamp': {}
        'f:message': {}
        'f:reason': {}
        'f:source':
          'f:component': {}
        'f:type': {}
involvedObject:
  kind: TargetGroupBinding
  namespace: default
  name: k8s-default-proxyngi-1c76e22ad3
  uid: e6e56ba2-82b6-76aafb51c753-f4a4d9812632
  apiVersion: elbv2.k8s.aws/v1beta1
  resourceVersion: '238786'
reason: SuccessfullyReconciled
message: Successfully reconciled
source:
  component: targetGroupBinding
firstTimestamp: '2021-02-16T15:50:37Z'
lastTimestamp: '2021-02-21T12:52:52Z'
count: 131
type: Normal
eventTime: null
reportingComponent: ''
reportingInstance: ''
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Kubeclt get events` command displays a list of events that have occurred in the cluster. The `SuccessfullyReconciled` event is one of the events that can be displayed by this command. When you see this event, it means that the controller responsible for the resource has successfully brought it into the desired state, and the resource is now ready to be used by other components of the system.

The `SuccessfullyReconciled` event in Kubernetes is generated by controllers to indicate that they have successfully reconciled the current state of a resource with its desired state. When a controller detects a change in the state of a resource, it takes appropriate actions to bring it into the desired state.